# JQuery Validation with Multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple buttons that can be clicked, and it's currently processed by php. The current code for buttons is this:

```
<button id="btn_back" class='ym-button ym-success' name="action_back">Back</button>

<button id="btn_finish" class='ym-button ym-success' name="action_finish">Place Order</button>
```

And processing on php looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['action_back'])) {
    ...
}

if (isset($_POST['action_finish'])) {
    ...
}
```

Now I want to add JQuery validation for one of the buttons (action_finish) before sending the form, but struggling how to keep the information about which button has been clicked. I don't want to over-complicate the html part by adding one more hidden field, and preferably the other buttons should be submitted in normal way with no JS intervention.

My js code would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("init");

    $("#btn_finish").click(function () {
        console.log("clicking finish");

        // validation
        ...

        $("#form1").submit();
    });

});
```

Somehow I would need to prevent the submit for this button click, but the POST field 'action_finish' should be persisted or added back using JS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you should use preventDefault() after your clicking function:

```
$("#btn_finish").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
...
```

This stops the form submission, so you can do your checks after that and finally submit the form when everything is okay. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have tried this, however my problem is that I cannot preserve the clicked button information, i.e. the post field action_finish doesn't exists. I guess there is a way to add that post field back to the information to be submitted, it would solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps from official documentation: `$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" ) {
    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
    return;
  }
 
  $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: What this basically does is that you can assign a function to the submit method and do your validation there while keeping track of the original button source. If you modify this example a little bit it should be exactly what you want I hope...

Comment: If there are two submit button, i.e. btn_back and btn_finish, is there a way to check in the above function which is clicked?

Comment: Sure, change your `$("#btn_finish").click(function () { ...` with a class selector and pass argument e to the function, like so: `$(".ym-button").click(function (e) { ...` and inside this function you can get any information you want from the button by using `e.target`. For example e.target.id gives you the id of the button that was clicked. But you can also get the name attribute of course. Does this help you out?